# get dom text by line in js

Tags: javascript, html, gsap

if I have some text on my dom that looks like this

```html
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
Dolorum omnis accusamus ex impedit quas, magnam possimus
eum aspernatur delectus pariatur neque commodi voluptatibus
rerum odio sint voluptates! Sequi iste non perferendis. 
</p>
```

is there any way for me to see where the line breaks are?

I want to animate each line fading in but for dynamic content that works responsively so I can't be the one setting the line breaks.

One convoluted way I found was to take the text, wrap every word in a span, measure the offset of each span and sort them that way, but that method is pretty inefficient.

Comment: You mean line breaks because of wrapping, not line breaks in the HTML markup?

Comment: i dont know if it's possible, but this should be doable without knowing line breaks. like create x divs each with height equal to line height of p to cover p, then animate each div to create the effect. (not sure if this works)

Comment: Solution really depends on what you want to happen and the existing CSS....

Answer (score 1):

GSAP's [SplitText plugin](https://greensock.com/splittext/) does this for you! Check out [this demo](https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/mvhak?editors=0100) and [the docs](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/SplitText) for more information and demos.

```
const mySplitText = new SplitText("p", {type:"words,chars"}), 
const chars = mySplitText.chars; // an array of all the divs that wrap each character

tl.from(chars, {duration: 0.8, opacity:0, scale:0, y:80, rotationX:180, transformOrigin:"0% 50% -50",  ease:"back", stagger: 0.01}, "+=0");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` function over line breaks (`\n`):

```js
const pEl = document.getElementById('text')

console.log(pEl.innerHTML.split('\n'))
```

```html
<p id="text">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit.
Dolorum omnis accusamus ex impedit quas, magnam possimus
eum aspernatur delectus pariatur neque commodi voluptatibus
rerum odio sint voluptates! Sequi iste non perferendis. 
</p>
```

Comment: this doesn't work if there aren't any \n line breaks in the text itself, if the text just wraps because of its container

Comment: Oh ok, I don't think you can detect line breaks created by the html container

Comment: One idea would be to use a monospaced font, with fixed letter width. You measure the container width, then you divided by character width + letter spacing so you get the amount of characters by rows